# Workaround Chrome issue 423256: scrolling multiple select into view

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

## Update: Issue solved with latest Chrome update

I work on a website that is affected by [Chrome/Chromium issue 423256](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423256). It makes the browser scroll a multiple select with a selected option into view on load.

Testcase taken from the issue http://jsfiddle.net/kLbfpdLf/1/:

```
<div style="height:10000px"></div>
    <select multiple="multiple">
    <option>option</option>
    <option>option</option>
    <option selected="selected">option</option>
    <option>option</option>
</select>
```

Now I try to find a workaround for that. I know no way to intercept before the the browser finishes displaying the select. So I remove the selections from the HTML and instead supply a data attribute with these values. Later I temporarily hide the select and select the options:

```
$elem.hide();
$elem.val($elem.data('selected').split(','));
$elem.show();
```

Please see the full example on http://jsfiddle.net/kLbfpdLf/2/.

Do you have a idea that works without deselecting the options?

Thanks.

### Update 1

I moved to an approach where the select is initially hidden via `style="display:none"`. And then shown after the page has been loaded. For details see: http://jsfiddle.net/kLbfpdLf/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by the vendor. No workaround needed.